# Why can a script with a "#!/bin/sh" shebang use bash-only features?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, git-bash

When I run the following script :

```
#!/bin/sh

declare path="my.path"

if [[ "$path" =~ \. ]] ; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

I got `yes` printed.

But if I am not mistaken, `declare` and `[[ ]]` are not available in POSIX shell ; so how come this script does not throw any error ?

I run the script on git for Windows, could it explain this odd behavior ?

Comment: `sh` can be any POSIX compatible shell. This script is likely to work on GitBash/WSL/macOS/OpenBSD (because `sh` is provided by bash or ksh) but not on Debian/Ubuntu/Android/FreeBSD. If you stick to POSIX features, it'll work on every system. If you specify `bash`, it'll work on every system where bash is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/bin/sh` is a link to your actual shell. It does not mean that you are running pure POSIX. The [Git for windows homepage](https://gitforwindows.org/) makes very clear that you are running `bash`, as does your `git-bash` tag.

Even on Linux, `/bin/sh` can still be bash:

```
ls -la /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Mar 27 09:33 /bin/sh -> bash
```

Comment: Just a little extra question, if git runs my script on a bash environment no matter the shebang, how come a script with the shebang `#!/bin/bash` allows function name like `lib::func()` but a script with the shebang `#!/bin/sh` throws the following error : `lib::func : not a valid identifier` ?

Comment: @JordanRepovy This is because Bash has a POSIX compatibility mode that's enabled when it's invoked as `sh` or `bash --posix` or `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 bash`. In this mode, certain features are disabled or modified. Search `man bash` for `posix mode` for the long list of features affected

Comment: @thatotherguy Oh yes I forgot about that ! Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: The key thing to note is that POSIX acknowledges `[[` as a reserved word without *requiring* any special meaning for it. That means `/bin/sh` is allowed to optionally support it (which `bash` does even when invoked as `sh`).